# Find duplicate tags in xml with c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Hi I got the xml below

```
<InstanceData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <letter>
        <variableBlocks>
            <VariableBlockBase xsi:type="ClientVariableBlock">
                <FirstName></FirstName>
                <LastName></LastName>
                <Address></Address>
            </VariableBlockBase>
            <VariableBlockBase xsi:type="PaymentVariableBlock">
                <LastPaymentDate></LastPaymentDate>
                <LastPaymentAmount></LastPaymentAmount>
                <Address></Address> <!-- repeated (Address appear in the VariableBlockBase above) so this xml should be invalid -->
            </VariableBlockBase>
      </variableBlocks>
    </letter>
</InstanceData>
```

That xml is being build **dynamically**.
Each `<VariableBlockBase>` have a set or variables (FirstName, Address, etc)
There are 2 contraints that I want to check

1. A "variable" or element  is not repeated within a `<VariableBlockBase>`
2. A "variable" or element only appear in one `<VariableBlockBase>`

In the example xml see that `<Address>` appear in both `<VariableBlockBase>` instances (Client and Payment)

I want to create a Linq query to get a List of repeated tags. I got this xml in a XmlDocument instance.

Comment: Do you mean "just within `VariableBlockBase` elements"? Is that *all* `VariableBlockBase` elements, or just those within the same `letter` element? You need to make your requirements really, really clear.

Comment: Each variableBlock have a set of variables, variables cannot be in more than one variableblock and within its own block.   In the example xml, Address is repeated. I want to detect that.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify that - noting that currently your XML has `variableBlocks`, not `variableBlock`.

Comment: Build xsd schema and validate xml with schems: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-validate-using-xsd-linq-to-xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about putting all the code in one linq query but here is non-linq solution:

```
string xml = @"<InstanceData xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-
instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
                            <letter>
                            <variableBlocks>
                                <VariableBlockBase xsi:type=""ClientVariableBlock"">
                                    <FirstName></FirstName>
                                    <LastName></LastName>
                                    <Address></Address>
                                </VariableBlockBase>
                                <VariableBlockBase xsi:type=""PaymentVariableBlock"">
                                    <LastPaymentDate></LastPaymentDate>
                                    <LastPaymentAmount></LastPaymentAmount>
                                    <Address></Address> <!-- repeated (Address appear in the VariableBlockBase above) so this xml should be invalid -->
                                </VariableBlockBase>
                          </variableBlocks>
                        </letter>
                    </InstanceData>";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml);
        XmlNodeList allElements = doc.SelectNodes("//VariableBlockBase/*");
        foreach(XmlElement childNode in doc.SelectNodes("InstanceData/letter/variableBlocks/*"))
        {
            foreach ( XmlElement grandChildNode in childNode.ChildNodes )
            {
                try
                {
                    allElements.Cast<XmlElement>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == grandChildNode.Name);
                }
                catch ( InvalidOperationException )
                {
                    throw new Exception("The tag <" + grandChildNode.Name + "> has been found more than once");
                }
                catch
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: By the way, "non-linq solution" is wrong, since this utilizes LINQ.